# How to seamlessly decorate class

Tags: .net, json, json.net

I have some complex class hierarchy that realize all needed functionality. I'm referencing base abstract class from that hierarchy in my serialiazable class. I just need to add one extra property during serialization, but from side it should like that property has always been in that class. Right now json.net wraps it into name of property.

```
public class SerializeMe
{
  AbstractValidation _validation;
  public SerializeMe(AbstractValidation validation)
  {
     this._validation = validation;
  }

  [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "designer|displayName")]
  public string DisplayName
  {
    get { return string.Concat(_validation.Field, _validation.Type); }
  }

  public AbstractValidation Validation
  {
     get
     {
        return _validation;
     }
  }
}
```

What I get, for example:

```
 {
   "DisplayName":"F_Director_Empl_Rolepresence",
   "Validation":{
      "type":"presence",
      "field":"F_Director_Empl_Role"
    }
  }
```

I need:

```
 {
   "DisplayName":"F_Director_Empl_Rolepresence",
   "type":"presence",
   "field":"F_Director_Empl_Role"
 }
```

Here I need to get rid of Validation section - as if DisplayName is part of AbstractValidation class. I could inherit classes from ancestors of AbstractValidation but hierarchy is quite complex. Instead, I'm searching the way to decorate classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to make a custom `JsonConverter` for your `SerializeMe` class in order to do what you want.  Perhaps something like this:

```
class CustomConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == typeof(SerializeMe);
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        SerializeMe sm = (SerializeMe)value;

        // Get child properties into a JObject
        JObject obj = JObject.FromObject(sm.Validation);

        // Now add the parent properties we're interested in
        obj.Add("DisplayName", sm.DisplayName);

        // Write the object to the output
        obj.WriteTo(writer);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Once you have the converter, decorate your `SerializeMe` class with a `[JsonConverter]` attribute so that Json.Net knows to use the custom converter:

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(CustomConverter))]
public class SerializeMe
{
    ...
}
```

Then, serialize as usual.  Here is a demo:

```
AbstractValidation av = new AbstractValidation
{
    Field = "F_Director_Empl_Role",
    Type = "presence"
};
SerializeMe sm = new SerializeMe(av);

string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(sm, Formatting.Indented);
Console.WriteLine(json);
```

Output:

```
{
  "Type": "presence",
  "Field": "F_Director_Empl_Role",
  "DisplayName": "F_Director_Empl_Rolepresence"
}
```